# Simulate multiple key presses

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a clicker for a game. It requires repeated pushing of a button, and about 10 seconds later to hold down a different button.

I want to press q over and over for ten seconds, and then hold c for 10 seconds, endlessly repeating this process, I've looked with Google, no keyboard clickers can do more than one key at a time.

Comment: Just use AutoHotkey. It's designed for uses just like that. Also, cheating is bad, mmkay?

Answer (score 0):

**PyUserInput** should do that!

It's a merge of two cool repositories: PyMouse and PyKeyBoard.

It allows you to control mouse and keyboard with Python and it's available in pip package manager.

Just try something like that:
keys = PyKeyboard()
while True:
    stop = time.time() # calculates time when to stop pressing Q

```
# start pressing Q for 10 seconds
while(time.time() < stop):
    keys.tap_key('Q')

keys.press_key('C') #start pressing C for 10 seconds
time.sleep(10) #sleeps for 10 seconds
keys.release_key('C') #releases C key
```

For make that work you will need to import time and PyUserInput libraries.